# parse sign up method error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to implement sign up method in my app and now I have problems with parse. i am trying the following:

```
func signUpSend() {
    var user = PFUser()
    user.username = email.text
    user.password = email.text
    user.password = password.text

    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        } else {
            let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
        }
    }
}
```

the signUpInBackgroundWithBlock gives me an error "cannot invoke 'signUpInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((Bool!,NSError!) -> Void)' . I have tried to find answer in the parse docs, but thats exactly the code they advise to use. Anybody knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
(succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

to

```
(succeeded, error) -> Void in
```

I believe this change is required due to changes in Swift 1.2 update

Comment: it works, huge thanks. But now the errorString gives an error telling me that it can't subscript a value of type [NSObject, AnyObject]? .

Comment: since this worked, please consider marking it as the answer :)

Comment: I will, I need to wait 4 minutes before I am allowed. Thanks a lot and good luck!